# grunt configuring with arguments

Tags: gruntjs

I have a file structure like:

```
app
    mobile_a
    mobile_b
    mods
```

And I use

```
var appConfig = {
    dist: 'build',
    programWildcard: 'mobile_*', 
};
...
grunt.registerTask('serve', [
    'replace:version',
    'clean:server',
    'concurrent:server',
    'underscore_jst',
    'replace:cmdWrap',
    'connect:livereload',
    'watch'
]);
```

and after I run `grunt serve`, I'll get

```
app
    build
        mobile_a
        mobile_b
    mobile_a
    mobile_b
    mods
```

But now, I only want to compile files in mobile_a and get:

```
app
    build
        mobile_a
    mobile_a
    mobile_b
    mods
```

So I wrote this:

```
grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile and start a connect web server', function(target) {
    appConfig.programWildcard = target;

    return grunt.task.run([
        'replace:version',
        'clean:server',
        'concurrent:server',
        'underscore_jst',
        'replace:cmdWrap',
        'connect:livereload',
        'watch'
    ]);
});
```

But when I run `grunt serve:mobile_a`, it still compile both mobile_a and mobile_b... Can anyone help me?

Comment: You can GET arguments like `grunt.option('argument_name_1')` and call them like `grunt ... --argument_name_1=string_example`

Comment: @eloibm Thanks, it is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eloibm's anwser is helpful. (Just answer to finish this question.)